# WebApi AuthorizationFilterAttribute: ActionArguments are empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm implementing an AuthorizationFilterAttribute for a WebApi controller, but I don't seem to have access to the parameters that are being passed into the controller:

In MVC4, this works fine:

```
public class MyMVCController : Controller
{
    [CanAccessMyResourceApi]
    public MyViewModel Get(int id)
    {
       //...
    }
}

public class CanAccessMyResourceMVCAttribute : CanAccessAttributeBase
{
   public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   {
       var param = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("id")
       /// ... 
   }
}
```

But in WebAPI, I think the parameter should be in the ActionArguments, but "param" here is empty:

```
public class MyWebApiController : ApiController
{
   [CanAccessMyResourceWebApi]
   public MyViewModel Get(int id)
   {
      //...
   }

}

public class CanAccessMyResourceWebApiAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {       
        // the debugger shows that ActionArguments is empty:
        var param = filterContext.ActionArguments["id"]
        /// ...
    }
}
```

Is the parameter that's being passed into the controller available somewhere else?  (I  verified that the controller's action is getting the Id value correctly when I remove the filter attribute.)

Comment: ParameterBinding happens after AuthorizationFilters are run in Web API, so i believe what you are seeing is expected behavior.

Comment: Looks like it can be done with an ActionFilterAttribute instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817202/accessing-post-or-get-parameters-in-custom-authorization-mvc4-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the solutions from **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817202/accessing-post-or-get-parameters-in-custom-authorization-mvc4-web-api)** StackOverflow page?

Specifically:

```
var variable = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["parameterName"];

public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
  {
     protected override bool IsAuthorized(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
     {
        var clientId = actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["clientid"];

     }
  }
```

Hope this helped!