# Access Get or Post parameters in MVC Web Api Authorization filter

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to achieve the same as [Accessing post or get parameters in custom authorization MVC4 Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817202/accessing-post-or-get-parameters-in-custom-authorization-mvc4-web-api) ,but it only works in the case of a GET request.

So I have written the follwoing action filter for a web api:

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext   actionContext)
    {
        var request = actionContext.Request;
        var headers = request.Headers;
        HttpContext ctx = default(HttpContext);
        ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        if (ctx != null)
        {
            var apiKey = (string)actionContext.ActionArguments["apiKey"];
        }            
    }
```

The form that posts looks like:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@localPostUrl">
<fieldset>
    <legend>File Upload Example</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="caption">Image Caption</label>
        <input name="caption" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="image1">Image File</label>
        <input name="image1" type="file" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="apiKey" id="apiKey" value="b2b54e7b-ca0b-4adf-a369-efe839e55120" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

So I'm trying to post an image and a string to the Web Api but the actionContext.ActionArguments in the ActionFilter is empty when doing a POST request but is working when doing a GET request.

When compared to the solution provided on top of my question I notice that the action where that posts has an attribute FormUri added to a parameter, but I can't send the ApiKey in the querystring.

Is there a solution to getting the Post paramteres in order to do some form on validation?