# Allow URL to access with Basicauthintication IIS

Tags: .net, security, iis, basic-authentication, iis-8

We have a website that we added a basic authentication, to allow only specific people to have access on as it is only in beta stage.

But one of 3rd party services stop working and i understand why, because the basic authentication is restricting it. I tried to add the service URL in IP Address and Domain Restrictions as allow.

but it is not working. I've searched around but couldn't find a lead, i have no good experience in IIS can you please be patient with me.

Comment: Revise your design is a must before moving on. Are you sure you want an external service to access without authentication while some internal users to be authenticated? That looks like something bad for me.

Comment: It is a service called usersnap. they are used to get feedback from users. but they access the website CSS and javascript and the page, and call it to there rendering engine. so it is not a problem once we go live.

Comment: Is this an MVC web app? I have had success enabling basic auth using the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12828402/222163

Comment: Then a better design would be a custom module loaded in ASP.NET pipeline to allow requests coming from the 3rd party IP address(es) with no authentication, while it sends custom 401.1 response to requests coming from other IP addresses to ask for credentials. When credentials do come with requests, this module parses them and sees if the requests belong to your beta testers. You cannot use IIS basic authentication, as that does not give you such flexibility.

Comment: That is what i did, thank you.