# Custom CustomAuthenticationAttribute depend parameter in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, permissions, roles, custom-authentication

How I can create `CustomAuthenticationAttribute` for an action in ASP.NET MVC 5 depend parameter, I mean if I sent to module 5, it means get data related teacher, and if I send 3 as parameter in module, return student. I want add two permissions (student and teacher) to allow user to access student or teacher or the both.

```
[CustomAuthentication(PermissionCode = "Student_View")]
public ActionResult Index(int module)
{
}
```

I have issue because the `CustomAuthentication` related page code (I will add two pieces of code) student_View and teacher_View

Comment: Attributes are applied at compile time, so they can’t behave differently based on a parameter

Comment: So, Any solution to fix this issue , check permission depend parameter, May be add validation in Action ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can still access action parameters using the passed in `AuthorizationContext` depending on how your attribute is setup, doing something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12828402/3850012). I am inheriting from `AuthorizeAttribute` but this should work for other types of attributes as long as you can get access to the `Request` object.

You could also make the `"module"` property name dynamic by passing it into the attribute:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {
    public string ParamName { get; set; }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParamName)) {
            if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[ParamName] != null) { // If using GET
                int module = int.Parse(filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[ParamName]);

                // Do something with module
            } else if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[ParamName] != null) { // If using POST (I have not tested Form before myself)
                int module = int.Parse(filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[ParamName]);

                // Do something with module
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you would use it like this:

```
[CustomAuthentication(ParamName = "module")]
public ActionResult Index(int module) { }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, But I want add permissionCode to allow user enter module , like if user add Student_View, it's mean enter student , and if add teacher_View , it's mean enter to teacher info, I want PermissionCode  to define it to user to control access to pages (fake page) because its the same page

Comment: Are you understand what I mean , if you can help me

Comment: @Sam Not sure I follow. Please provide more code in your question.